# Associated Labels with Selectbox

Tags: jquery, html

i have a question about associated labels with a select box.
I have a select box with 3 values:

```
  0
  1 -> AA
  2 -> AB
  3 -> AC
```

or see the picture below

[image: A selectbox with 3 values]

I have only a selectbox visible nothing other, because i had nothing choiced.
When i choice now the value AB see the picture below:

[image: Selected value AB]

then i want to get the associated label (with some inputfields) for this selected value!
see the picture below.

[image]

It must worked like radiobuttons. If i choose AA then i get another assoiciated label and the label what was choosen before will be invisible.
When i choose value "0" (Nothing), then must all labels be invisible.

[Here the (only) HTML structure](http://jsfiddle.net/SGZup/3/), because jquery is to heavy for me. If you have an example? I hope you can help me

THX in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SGZup/4/)

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select id="choice" name="choose">
            <option value="0"></option>
            <option value="1">AA</option>
            <option value="2">AB</option>
            <option value="3">AC</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

    <tr id="firstLast">
        <td class="mySaisie">&nbsp;Firstname</td>
        <td>
            <input id="name" name="fname" />
        </td>
        <td class="mySaisie">&nbsp;Lastname</td>
        <td>
            <input id="name" name="lname" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="addresses">
        <td class="mySaisie">&nbsp;Adresse 1</td>
        <td>
            <input id="adresse" name="fname" />
        </td>
        <td class="mySaisie">&nbsp;Adresse 2</td>
        <td>
            <input id="adresse" name="lname" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
​
```

JQUERY

```
$("#choice").on('change',function(){
    var $choice = $('#choice option:selected').val();
    if ($choice == 1) {
         $("#firstLast").show();   
    } else {
        $("#firstLast").hide(); 
    }

    if ($choice == 2) {
         $("#addresses").show();   
    } else {
        $("#addresses").hide(); 
    }
});​
```

CSS

```
#firstLast,#addresses {display:none;}​
```

I took out the excess code as it wasn't clear otherwise.

You shouldn't use labels to chunk code together in that way. :)

[More info on using labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)